# augmented reality framework

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am planning to develop an augmented reality application for Android phone. Does anyone know if there is any existing framework for augmented reality which could be used for such applications?

Comment: Any tutorial to start with??

Comment: There is good news, Google announced ARCore!
https://developers.google.com/ar/

Comment: ArCore is limited to a few devices, so still not a good idea for production development. How can they call that a 1.0 version?

Comment: over 100 upvotes but closed lol.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

For ideas, you could look at the following:

**Existing Apps and their APIs:**
There are number of Augmented Reality applications in the Android market of which Layar and Wikitude are well known. Others like [SomaView](http://www.chrismc.de/development/somaview/) and [GeoVector](http://www.geovector.com/) also exist. AFAIK, [Wikitude](http://www.wikitude.org/category/developer) and [Layar](http://layar.com/blog/2009/11/05/layar-rapid-development-tools/) have made their API's public.

**Toolkit:**
There is also a toolkit named, [NyARToolkit](http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wp/) that provides a library for such a thing.

**Tutorial:**
[DevX Article by Chris Haseman](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42482/1954)

Good Luck!

Comment: Also have a look at Junaio http://www.junaio.com/develop/

Comment: I would also add that it depends if you want do do location based AR or vision based (e.g. marker based) AR. I would say that on android for vision based ar http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/ is realy good and for location based you can also try http://droidar.googlecode.com/ or http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/ for open source SDKs

Comment: The Wikitude link is outdated: Everything around SDK and developer related stuff can be found at: [developer.wikitude.com](http://developer.wikitude.com)
The Wikitude SDK is mixing both approaches - location based or sensor based Augmented Reality and computer vision AR

Comment: Aurasma currently offers their technology for free (standalone or embedded in other apps): http://www.aurasma.com/become-a-partner

Answer (score 14):

You can also use the new Qualcomm AR SDK
http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/augmented-reality

Comment: from aualcomm i am able download samples but i am getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: setActivityPortraitMode this exception after running sample.please suggest me how to slove this issue.

Comment: You have to build and compile the NDK part of it using cygwin, follow the tutorial on https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-3-compiling-running-vuforia-sample-app

Comment: NB: This one supports ONLY vision-based AR.

Answer (score 12):

There are two types of augmented reality:

a) marker based, which needs bidimensional markers to recognize using computer vision and image analysis to draw an image over them with the corresponding rotation (ARToolkit)

b) geolocation and orientation based, which means that the app knows the exact position in the earth where you are, and what are you facing and it computes what you see, based on geolocation. (layar,wikitude)

Apps like junaio mixes both of them

Comment: There's also what is considered "markerless" based AR that use natural features in a video frame to create a pose matrix which can be used to render virtual objects. This is basically how Vuforia works - https://developer.qualcomm.com/develop/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality

Comment: I've used Junaio too :) I prefer Vuforia though... I'm pretty sure you need to buy a license to release any apps you build with Junaio

Answer (score 12):

This page http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks shows a broad comparative of augmented reality framworks. Is **updated to March 2013**.

It's featured

- IN2AR - http://www.in2ar.com/
- METAIO - http://www.metaio.com
- Vuforia - https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality

Comment: This chart is auto-updated

Comment: BTW, metaio is now closed. It is owned by Apple Inc.

Answer (score 9):

I'm one of the developers Look! Look! is a complete framework for creating augmented reality applications on Android.

It was developed as a final project at the University Complutense of Madrid.

Their features are:

- Augmented Reality
- Location Indoor
- Remote Services
- 3D, 2D and Camera
- Iterations with objects

Furthermore we have developed apps with the framework, theirs are published in our official web.

More information:

Official website - http://www.lookar.net/en/

Project stayed in – https://sourceforge.net/projects/lookar/

Comment: I developed with this framework, it was pretty well done

Comment: is there any document for integration look! to my app. Also can it be used for showing POIs

Comment: Official website is down? says Error 522. Website is offline No cached version of this page is available.

Answer (score 7):

Check out Mixare. It's a pretty nice AR framework for Android. Unlike most of the previously mentioned suggestions (I'm not sure about all of them), source code is available for Mixare.

Answer (score 6):

Full open source marker based augmented reality framework.
http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/

Answer (score 2):

http://layar.com/ would be the most popular thing I've seen. I made an app that allows for downloading and displaying of information much the same way as layar. It's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, I maintain the AndroidARKit, an open source project on github.  It's geographic based and includes a simple foursquare example application.  More info [here](http://www.hasemanonmobile.com/2009/11/15/announcing-the-android-ar-kit/). or [here](http://github.com/haseman/Android-AR-Kit/).  I wrote the devX article linked above.  Feel free to contact me if you have any questions.  It's licensed for commercial use with attribution.  So feel free to use it in commercial apps.

Comment: Where can I get your contact?

Comment: twitter.com/androidarkit

Comment: or haseman at wanderingoak dot net

Answer (score 2):

I know a [FLOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) system that help you to create AR applications. This system is [LibreGeoSocial](http://www.libregeosocial.org)

Answer (score 2):

Anyone interested in AR should also take a look at http://code.google.com/p/droidar/

Its an open-source framework for location based and marker based AR on Android.

Comment: I am trying to mark some geopoints using droidar . DO you have any similar projects for reference

Comment: Just take a look at the many example setups in the "de.rwth.setups" package in the DroidAR project folder. And watch the introduction videos, they should give you a first overview

Comment: I had watched all those videos and tried the demo projects. Got a rough idea. Have you used this in any of your projects ? I wanted to know how good is it . I am really confused which framework to use. I want to show some point of interest. As the user move , it shoul show those pints which are visible . Thanks a lot for your help and answer

Comment: If you want to do location based AR on Android its definitely a good idea to use it. And if you have problems just post a question to the issues section, normally you should get help very fast.

Answer (score 2):

The pioneer in AR metaio(Developers of Junaio) will release a free version of the [metaio Mobile SDK](http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/) (Q4/2011). :)

Comment: will be released today (8th December 2011) :)

Comment: it was acquired by apple on 2015

Answer (score 2):

[BeyondAR](http://beyondar.com/platform) is free and apache license v2

Answer (score 1):

I know that [artoolkit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/) has a port to Symbian. Maybe there exists a port to Android as well

Answer (score 1):

The Wikitude API is another alternative for Android applications: http://www.wikitude.org/developers

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [Layar Player](http://www.layar.com/player/).

"The Layar Player is a tool that enables anyone to embed augmented reality layers directly into their very own application".

Currently the Layar Player is for iPhone only, but an Android version will be available in Q4 2011.

Answer (score 1):

[D’Fusion Mobile](https://community.t-immersion.com/) is a marker based and geolocation based Platform with BarCode Support, Face Tracking and Sensor Support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one ! An Open Source Project : http://code.google.com/p/andar/

Answer (score 0):

As reinier said, artoolkit could be the best option. there is for android, check [this](http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wiki/index.php?NyARToolkit%20for%20Android.en) out

Answer (score 0):

[ar23d](http://ar23d.com/) is a 3D Augmented Reality SDK for Android 2.2+ and Android 3.0+. How much are the licensing costs can not be found on their website.

Answer (score 0):

This [Android augmented reality library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939318/augmented-reality-framework) enables you to convert GPS (lat/lon) coordinates to screen (x/y) coordinates. It's a simple jar import and handles all calculations for you.

Answer (score -1):

I think You should use String SDK

http://www.poweredbystring.com/licensing

Download the project zip file from

https://github.com/kyleroche/Professional_iOS_AugmentedReality/blob/master/Ch10/mobile/mobile/ViewController.m

Then open CH-10 Project.That is locked with com.isidorey.mobile BundleIdentifier.
So You have create a provisioning profile in name isidoreywildcard* .
THen It will run.

But This is not the solution.

You need to run by using your own provisionin profile.

So first register in

http://www.poweredbystring.com/licensing

Then download the demoVersion to Try.
You can use the
libStringOGLPro-1.1-com-isidorey-mobile.a (You will get a .a static library from downloaded Demo Project)
static library to check your project.

Its Better to read the book

[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-iOS-5-Augmented-Reality/dp/1430239123](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430239123)

Comment: String SDK is only for iOS.

Comment: Yes String SDK is only for IOS .

Comment: the guys asked for frameworks on android phones, not ios.