# Augmented Reality (Android): loading trackable dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, sdk, augmented-reality, targets

I am looking for a (marker based) framework (SDK) that allows you, for example, the trackables update via Web-services. Without traditionally recompiling and installing a new apk.

Maybe someone has experiences with one of these [framewoks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939318/augmented-reality-framework).

Unfortunately, it works not now with Qualcomm's SDK. The trackables can not be loaded or linked to at runtime. You have to build them into the APK. :(

Comment: it's very simple in vuforia 1.5 ,see my ans [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580200/1206201)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QCAR SDK 1.5 Beta now supports swapping datasets at runtime! :)