# Load dataset from Internet QCAR v1.5

Tags: qcar-sdk

I'm writting an application that can load Dataset from internet at runtime ( i'm using QCARV1.5)

I heard that QCAR v1.5 supports this.

is there anyone have experience about loading dataset from internet at runtime  with QCAR v1.5?

Answer (score 1):

you can download Dataset from server and store in sdcard then in imagetarget.cpp in loadTrackerData change `QCAR::DataSet::STORAGE_APPRESOURCE` to `QCAR::DataSet::STORAGE_ABSOLUTE`.
 Everytime you download dataset just replace old one before calling load dataset from java,this will work.

Answer (score 0):

They have announced that the next version of Vuforia will be cloud-based which fetch the data from Internet. But meanwhile, the answer that @yogi has given is the best choice.

This is not actually related to Vuforia but it's just downloading file from Internet in Android.