# Android APIs for Augmented reality - gps and compass

Tags: android, gps, augmented-reality, compass-geolocation

I am building an Augmented Reality app in which I am stuck with integrating GPS and compass. Are there any APIs out there to achieve this goal?

Comment: This link below may get you started.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939318/augmented-reality-framework

Answer (score 0):

Here is the api info for gps:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used one useful library.. Hope the same will work for you too.

http://code.google.com/p/andar/

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for detailed tutorials or apis for a long time but i didn't find anything. The simpler version of the frameworks which is open-source and easy to make changes on it is the [augmented reality framework](http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/). It is similar to mixare.