# Begining with Android Augmented Reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-library

I am going to use augmented reality very soon
can anybody guide me what is android augmented reality?
which library can i use to implement AR in android

Comment: In work I'm using metaio - it is really good library and have a lot of example - [link](http://www.metaio.com/sdk/). It is for showing models/content in mobile camera

Comment: ok thanks...will soon come up with more queries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ease of entry: Metaio Creator to get a feel for AR scenarios without having to dive right into code.

More advanced work: Unity Plugins by Vuforia or Metaio SDK to build out complex interactions.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what type of development you want to get into I would suggest properly researching your platform options.

Your first question should be whether you're getting into location or image based AR. Image based AR is a lot more involved and I would suggest using an existing SDK. Location based AR is a lot simpler, to the point where you could get something working over a weekend.

There are also a lot of platforms available, the major ones being metaio, layar, wikitude, and vuforia (native or with Unity3D).

If you're interested in my personal opinion:
If you're looking to create a simple AR solution for a business then go with something like metaio, layar or wikitude.
If you're looking to implement a complex image based AR solution, consider using vuforia.
If you're looking to learn about AR technologies, I would suggest starting with vuforia, then implementing your own location AR solution.
If you're going to make a game, use Unity3D with Vuforia.

All the best!

Edit: Also take a look at this question: [augmented reality framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939318/augmented-reality-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at a project called mixare. I havent messed with it for over a year so I dont know if its actively supported but its definitely worth taking a look at.