# marker based augmented reality api

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am trying to develop an marker based augmented reality app which will recognize marker and draw an image at that particular position. I checked ARToolkit. But I am not sure whether can I place any image(not model) after rcognizing marker at particular position or not? Can anyone suggest me if there is any framework for developing such type of application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out the following existing answers from this stackoverflow thread: [augmented reality framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939318/augmented-reality-framework?rq=1)

This page http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks also contains a lot of AR frameworks (maybe too much).

- IN2AR - http://www.in2ar.com/
- METAIO - http://www.metaio.com
- WIKITUDE SDK - http://developer.wikitude.com/documentation/android
- Vuforia - https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality