# How get a reference to the camera instance

Tags: android, arcore

I'm developing an AR application using ARCore and got stuck in the following issue.

I want to get the Camera instance, that the ARCore session initializes, in order to configure it myself(change preview resolution, bitrate, white balance and so on).

Unfortunately, ARCore uses an object called Session(which is also part of ARCore lib) which uses Tango(was taken from Tango Project). The Tango object handles the hardware camera through JNI calls.

ARCore doesn't have API to configure the camera and getting it through reflection seems like a bad idea.

Anybody?

Comment: I asked for the same question [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846700/ar-core-performance-learning-curve-and-comparison-with-other-frameworks). I would like to learn about ARCore, if you wish to share some opinion on the subject, it would be awsome.

Comment: @Thracian the smartest advice that I can give you is to neglect ARCore for now and start to develop on ARKit(iOS). It much more stable and mature.